# How do I resolve this Angular 7 "Circular dependency detected" warning

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, angular7, warnings

In my Angular 7 project, I want to have a file "pages.ts" where I export the routes my app is going to have. These are imported by "app-routing.ts" to be used by the RouterModule, and also imported by "pages.service.ts" where I want to manage the data of those routes. Now, in one of my components "test-one.component.ts" I want to use that service "pages.service.ts" so I can get for example the data of a route by its path or title. Everything works properly but this warning appears.

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/pages/test-one/test-one.component.ts -> src/app/core/services/pages.service.ts -> src/app/core/constants/pages.ts -> src/app/pages/test-one/test-one.component.ts

**"pages.ts"**

```
import { Page } from '../../core/models/page.model';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../pages/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../pages/signup/signup.component';

export const routePages: Page[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        canActivate: [],
        data: {
            title: 'Login',
            description: '',
            keywords: '',
            icon: 'fingerprint',
            hasBreadcrumb: true
        },
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'sign-up',
        component: SignupComponent,
        canActivate: [],
        data: {
            title: 'Sign up',
            description: '',
            keywords: '',
            hasBreadcrumb: true
        },
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

**"app-routing.module.ts"**

```
import { routePages } from './core/constants/pages';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routePages, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**"pages.service.ts"**

```
import { routePages } from './../constants/pages';
import { Page, PageData } from './../models/page.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PagesService {
  pages = routePages;
  private pagesChanged: EventEmitter<Page[]> = new EventEmitter<Page[]>();

  constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {
    this.setPagesFullPath();
    console.log(this.pages);
  }
.
.
.

}
```

**"test-one.component.ts"**

```
import { Page, PageData } from './../../core/models/page.model';
import { PagesService } from './../../core/services/pages.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-one',
  templateUrl: './test-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-one.component.scss']
})
export class TestOneComponent implements OnInit {
  testATwoPage: Page;

  constructor(private pagesService: PagesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testATwoPage = this.pagesService.getPageByTitle('Test A two');
  }

}
```

I'd love to know how I could resolve this circular dependency without having to dispense with any functionalities.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one direct way around it. I understand your use-case though, and kinda support it. You should not have this kind of logic in your component. It should be done in a service. You are right about that. I'm not entirely sure it's the best idea to reuse the `Routes` export. It feels like you are better of using the `Router.config` property. Which should contain the entire route config:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PagesService {
  readonly pages: Routes = this.router.config;
  private pagesChanged: EventEmitter<Page[]> = new EventEmitter<Page[]>();

  constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {
    this.setPagesFullPath();
    console.log(this.pages);
  }
}
```

---

If this, for whatever reasons doesn't work. The way to get rid of circular dependencies is by splitting into multiple files. The main issue is your `routePages`. You can convert this to two files. One being pages.ts:

**pages.ts**

```
export enum PageRoute {
  Login: 'login',
  SignUp: 'sign-up'
}

export interface PageData {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  keywords: string;
  icon?: string;
  hasBreadcrumb: boolean;
}

export const PageRouteData: Record<PageRoute, PageData> {
  [AppPage.Login]: {
    title: 'Login',
    description: '',
    keywords: '',
    icon: 'fingerprint',
    hasBreadcrumb: true
  },
  [AppPage.SignUp]: {
    title: 'Sign up',
    description: '',
    keywords: '',
    hasBreadcrumb: true
  }
}
```

And another file which actually contains your routes which are digested by the router:

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routePages: Page[] = [
  {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: PageRoute.Login,
      pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
      path: PageRoute.Login,
      component: LoginComponent,
      data: PageRouteData[PageRoute.Login]
  },
  {
      path: PageRoute.SignUp,
      component: SignupComponent,
      data: PageRouteData[PageRoute.SignUp]
  }
];
```

<sub>Side note: `pathMatch` is only necessary if you have a `redirectTo`</sub>

This way you do not need to import the `app.routes` in your `PagesService` and the circular dependency is resolved

Comment: Yep, this.router.config was exactly what I needed. It works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @JuanLuisLópez You're welcome. I've expanded my answer a bit, you can use a combination of both. This way you get type hinting, even when you are working with route data

Comment: @JuanLuisLópez - Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry! This was my first question here. Done.

Comment: Thank you for saving my night.. @PoulKruijt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose of the PageService but I think that is wrong. To access the data of the router you should use the Router events or ActivatedRoute and then do whatever you have to do. For example in this piece of code I'm getting the info from the route to use in breadcrumbs:

```
this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => {
          return this.getFirstChild(this.route.firstChild);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(child => {
        const title = child.snapshot.data['title'];
        const previous = child.snapshot.data['previous'];
        const parentUrl = child?.snapshot.parent?.url;
        ...
      })
```

Comment: I use that service, for example, to generate a side menu automatically with all pages I specified I want to appear in it.

Comment: Check the property router.config from Router. I think that is you need.